# PHP Error - Undefined variable - unset($name);

Tags: php, variables, undefined

Noob learning to become a Web developer here. On a PHO module of my study course right now and hitting a bit of a bug.

Anyone able to explain to me why unset($name); is causing an error message to get thrown?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<?php

$myArray=array("pizza","chocolate","coffee");

print_r($myArray);

echo $myArray[1];

echo "<br /><br />";

$anotherArray[0]="pizza";
$anotherArray[1]="yoghurt";

print_r($anotherArray);

echo "<br /><br />";

$thirdArray=array(

    "France" => "French",
    "USA" => "English",
    "Germany" => "German",

);

print_r($thirdArray);

$anotherArray[]="salad";

echo "<br /><br />";

print_r($anotherArray);

echo "<br /><br />";

unset($thirdArray["Germany"]);

print_r($thirdArray);

echo "<br /><br />";

$name="Rob";

unset($name);

echo $name;

?>
```

Comment: after unset($name) you are trying to echo it so it throws error

Comment: you are echoing unset variable thats why you got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use any variable you have just `unset()`. [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) is here to explicitly destroy a variable that cannot be longer used.

Therefore, it should be:

```
<?php
// first, set $name
$name = 'Rob';
// then, use it
echo $name;
// at last, unset it
unset($name);

echo $name // will finally output an error.
```

Instead of the other way around.

Comment: Glad you made it work! Please also consider upvoting the answer if it helped you.